# How to revert save changes of an entity dbcontext

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I need to save multiple tables in my entity context at different times. If one of the save change methods runs but another save change method for a different table fails I am trying to revert the database back to it's original state.

To achieve this I am trying to create two entity contexts, seen below. The first entity I will change and call the SaveChanges method on the different tables when needed. However if an error occurs I am trying to then use the second entity context to overwrite any changes to the database that occurred so far.

Is there a way to overwrite the database values with the "origianlEntityValues" context I created at the start of the program?

Code samples below to hopefully explain it clearer

I instantiate two entity contexts at the start of my program (they inherit from DbContext). One I will make changes to. The other i am trying to use in case an error occurs to revert the changes

```
SystemEntities entity = new SystemEntities();
SystemEntities originalEntityValues = new SystemEntities();
```

Throughout the program I need to save tables individually as I need to get their generated Id values and use them in the other entity classes which I then go on to call save changes on, so I call code like this

```
entity.Contact.SaveChanges();
.... 
entity.Transact.SaveChanges();
```

If the first save changes runs fine but the second causes an error I am trying to use the 
"originalEntityValues" to overwrite the previous save changes calls so my database has the same values when the program started in the event of an unexpected error.

```
catch{  
  // refresh the database with the originalEntityValues context?
}
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to wrap this into 1 large [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)? When something went wrong, the data are not written until [TransactionScope.Complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is called.

Comment: I think i will still have an issue using this, as I need to save the contact table to the database so it can generate an Id (primary key) for it, which i then use in a transact record.

Comment: Never mind just done some tests and the tranactionscope works perfectly. Thanks a lot! Would upvote you but don't have enough rep